# Execute sql scripts in sequence using XML config file based on the child node values

Tags: sql, xml, loops, powershell, foreach

I have the XML config file that is defined as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Scripts>
    <Script Server = ".\" DBName = "Intelligence_FO_Local"     Sequence = "1"   sql = "PreDeployment_265015_Add_column_TotalAmount.sql"/>  
    <Script Server = ".\" DBName = "Intelligence_FO_Local"     Sequence = "2"   sql = "PreDeployment_265375_Add_column_IsPassFloorViolaton.sql"/>
    <Script Server = ".\" DBName = "Intelligence_FO_Local"     Sequence = "3"   sql = "PreDeployment_265915_Add_Columns_InferredMemberSource.sql"/>
    <Script Server = ".\" DBName = "Intelligence_FO_Local"     Sequence = "1"   sql = "Predeployment_266364_AddPSOKeyAndOffsrpingDirectorCount.sql"/>
    <Script Server = ".\" DBName = "Intelligence_FO_Local"     Sequence = "1"   sql = "PreDeployment_267185_DropTheOLdRelationshiphistoryTable.sql"/>
    <Script Server = ".\" DBName = "Intelligence_FO_Local"     Sequence = "1"   sql = "PreDeployment_268731_Add_Column_TaxExemptStatus_to_DimOrder.sql"/>
    <Script Server = ".\" DBName = "Intelligence_FO_Local"     Sequence = "1"   sql = "AM_QA_Contacts.sql"/>
    <Script Server = ".\" DBName = "Intelligence_FO_Local"     Sequence = "1"   sql = "QA_Intelligence_AM.sql"/>
    <Script Server = ".\" DBName = "Intelligence_Audit_Local"  Sequence = "1"   sql = "AuditScripts.sql"/>
    <Script Server = ".\" DBName = "Intelligence_FO_Local"     Sequence = "1"   sql = "AuditScripts.sql"/>
</Scripts>
```

I need to change the powershell script in such a way that it runs all the sql files mentioned in the XML which have sequence 1 and then run all the ones which have sequence 2 and so on. So, Sequence 2 scripts should only be run after sequence 1 finishes. Currently the below script only executing for sequence 1.

```
[xml]$xml =  [xml] (Get-Content -Path $configfile)  
  $Scripts= $xml.SelectNodes("/Scripts/Script")

  foreach ($Script in $Scripts | where {$_.Sequence -eq "1"} ) {
        $sqlfilename = $Script.getAttribute("sql")
        $Server = $Script.getAttribute("Server") 
        $DBName = $Script.getAttribute("DBName")
        $filename = $sqlfilename.Replace(".sql", "")
        $ps1 = $location + "\" + $sqlfilename.Trim()
        $ErrorOutputFile = "Error_output_{0}_{1}.txt" -f $filename.Trim(), $OutputDate


        If (Test-Path -path $ps1) { 
             add-content $logfile "- Started:  $ps1 " 
            $commandLine = "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $DBName -InputFile $ps1"
            Start-Process "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList $commandLine  -RedirectStandardError "$Outputlocation\$ErrorOutputFile" #-ErrorAction silentlycontinue
            add-content $logfile "----------------------------------------"
            $i++;           
         }
        Else {
            add-content $logfile "- File not found: $ps1 " 
            add-content $logfile "----------------------------------------"  
            $x++;                       
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this :

```
$configfile="C:\temp\config.xml"
$logfile="C:\temp\Log.txt"

[xml]$xml =  [xml] (Get-Content -Path $configfile)  

$xml.SelectNodes("/Scripts/Script") | sort Sequence | foreach {

        $sqlfilename = $_.Sql.Trim()
        $ps1 = "$location\$sqlfilename"

        if (!(Test-Path -path $ps1))
        {
            add-content $logfile "- File not found: $ps1 " 
            add-content $logfile "----------------------------------------"  
            $x++ 
            continue
        }

        $filename = $sqlfilename.Replace(".sql", "").Trim()
        $ErrorOutputFile = "Error_output_{0}_{1}.txt" -f $filename, $OutputDate

        add-content $logfile "- Started:  $ps1 " 
        $commandLine = "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance {0} -Database {1} -InputFile {2}" -f $_.Server, $_.DBName, $ps1 
        Start-Process "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList $commandLine  -RedirectStandardError "$Outputlocation\$ErrorOutputFile" #-ErrorAction silentlycontinue
        add-content $logfile "----------------------------------------"
        $i++;  
}
```

Explanation:

I have sorted by sequence and remove where clause.
I have restructured too by without obligation, just optimization

Comment: Thanks Esperento57. Sorting worked fine but is there a reason that you changed the if-else logic? In your case, once the file is not found, it is not continuing to the next scripts.

Comment: just better in performance, continue always say to continue into loop, not modidy scripy comportement